# How do you use javascript to get a random result from an array over a time interval?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I want the function *tim* below to get an ever changing route from Array every 500 milliseconds.  Instead, in my JS console I receive the following repeating error:

VM5550:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

What is going on here and what do I need to do to get the result I'm looking for?

My code:

```
var Array = ["http://files.parsetfss.com/9.png", 
"http://files.parsetfss.com/5.png",
"http://files.parsetfss.com/6.png",
"http://files.parsetfss.com/7.png",
"http://files.parsetfss.com/8.png"];

var sampl = _.first(_.sample(Array, 1));
var tim = setInterval(sampl, 500);
```

I also tried wrapping *sample* in a function like so:

```
var sampl = function(){return _.first(_.sample(Array, 1))};
```

I'm still not getting the desired result but now I'm getting a result that is consistently even 7 or 11 (after refeshing the screen a number of times.

Comment: `arr[Math.round(Math.random()*arr.length)]` something like this

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do. `tim` is not a function, neither is `sampl`, even though you seem to treat them as such. You'll have to show complete code.

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem, there are quite a few things that aren't defined, such as `_`. Along with that `setInterval` needs a function as the first argument.

Comment: @Juhana, that's why I tried wrapping it in a function but that didn't work either.  There is no more code than this I just want to return a different route from Array every 500ms.  Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way. I'm willing to try something else but what?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, _ is lodash

Comment: @rashadb does result have to be completely random or random among not presented already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should definitely change the name of your `var` to something else instead of overwriting the `Array` object.

Next, the `_.first` seems unnecessary. A sample of 1 is returning a string.

Run the snippet to see the desired effect.

```js
var arr = [
  "http://files.parsetfss.com/9.png", 
  "http://files.parsetfss.com/5.png",
  "http://files.parsetfss.com/6.png",
  "http://files.parsetfss.com/7.png",
  "http://files.parsetfss.com/8.png"
];

var tim = setInterval( function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = _.sample(arr);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you want the result to go. Your return doesn't seem to do anything with it, which may really be your issue.

Comment: this also looks promising. I want to connect the result to a randomly changing variable to put on a carousel on the front end. Could I use the result without document.body.innerHTML to do this?

Comment: If you want the result to be saved to a variable, just replace `document.body.innerHTML` to your variable's name. The syntax above is to make it worth with the snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function to `setInterval`, whereas you're passing it the result of running your array through underscore's `first` and `sample` methods (which in your case is a string). As @Tony points out, the use of `first` is unnecessary since the second parameter of the `sample` method specified the number of results you expect (see [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#sample)).

The following does what I think you're looking for:

```
var array = ["http://files.parsetfss.com/9.png", 
"http://files.parsetfss.com/5.png",
"http://files.parsetfss.com/6.png",
"http://files.parsetfss.com/7.png",
"http://files.parsetfss.com/8.png"];

function getRandom() {
    return _.sample(array, 1)[0];
} 

function showRandom() {
    console.log(getRandom());
}

// setInterval returns a pointer to the interval ...
var interval = setInterval(showRandom, 500);

// ... which you can use to stop it
//clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'm doing this because I want to create multiple variables whose values change every 500ms so I can connect each value to a carousel on the front end. It's hard to see if this will work as I can't get a result in the JS console; only a single number.

Comment: @rashadb - Okay, try pasting the updated version into the console on the underscore site. I can see why you were using first now, though I would probably do as I have above and get the first element by it's index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to get random element from array like this:

`var url = getRandomeEle(array);`

```
function getRandomEle(arr) {
   return arr[~~(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}
```

Comment: Why bother rehashing `_.sample`?

Comment: although op is using underscorejs, he doesnt tag it

Comment: `_.sample` returns a random element from an array. And even let's you choose a sample size, [doc](https://lodash.com/docs#sample). This method adds nothing.

Comment: op also doesn't mention if random values should be from values that haven't been shown yet.

Answer (score 0):

Good answers already and I agree with Tony that you really should change the variable name `Array`.

I presume you will want to stop this interval at some point in which case you will need to call `clearInterval`.

Here's a quick [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/za4qqUbXxzxN77mZ7xB8?p=preview).

**script.js**

```
var intervalId,

    startButton = document.getElementById('start'),
    stopButton  = document.getElementById('stop'),

    urls = [
      "http://files.parsetfss.com/9.png", 
      "http://files.parsetfss.com/5.png",
      "http://files.parsetfss.com/6.png",
      "http://files.parsetfss.com/7.png",
      "http://files.parsetfss.com/8.png"
    ];

startButton.addEventListener('click', tim, false);
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopTim, false);


function tim() {
  intervalId = setInterval(printRandomUrl, 500);
}

function stopTim(){
  clearInterval(intervalId)
}

function printRandomUrl(){
  console.log(_.sample(urls));
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@3.8.0" data-semver="3.8.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Basic plunk!</h1>
     <button id="start">Start</button>
     <button id="stop">Stop</button>

     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```